# AttributeError: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'validate_on_submit'

Tags: python, flask

Во [документации](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) и в огромном множестве примеров приводится validate_on_submit, однако при импорте validators ничего не меняется.
Из-за этой ошибки не удаётся залогинется.

Pycharm предлагает в models создать функцию:

```
def validate_on_submit(self):
    pass
```

Подскажите, кто знает как решить.

views.py:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        login_user(user)
        flash('Logged in successfully.')
        next = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_is_valid(next):
            return abort(400)
        return redirect(next or url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email = TextField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    password = PasswordField('Your Password', [
        validators.Required(),
    ])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember me', default=False)

    def validate_on_submit(self):
        pass
```

Comment: И да, не надо слушаться pycharm и сотрите свою функцию validate_on_submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примеру кода, вы используете формы из библиотеки [WTForms](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WTForms) примерно так:

```
from wtforms.form import Form
class LoginForm(Form):
    ...
```

Так вот, этот WTForms не имеет к Flask никакого отношения и ничего не знает про тот HTTP-запрос, который принят фласком. И функции `validate_on_submit` у него нет. Для валидации в таком случае вам следует воспользоваться функцией `validate`, подробнее про это можно прочитать в документации WTForms. Но лучше так не надо :)

Специально для интеграции с Flask существует [Flask-WTF](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-WTF), и его формы уже прекрано взаимодействуют с Flask и могут провести валидацию как положено автоматически без вашего участия. Вам следует установить его и создать форму так:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
```

После этого функция `validate_on_submit` появится и будет, собственно, проводить валидацию:

```
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
```

Заметьте, `request.form` в конструктор передавать не надо — форма Flask-WTF достаточно умная, чтобы достать его самостоятельно :) Подробнее про творящуюся здесь магию можно прочитать в [документации](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо.
До этого я не знал про FlaskForm.
Сделал всё, как описано в документации, но ловлю другую ошибку.
Что в таком случае делать ru.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik в таком случае это уже создавать новый вопрос, но тем временем внутренний телепат мне подсказывает, что другая ошибка эта `'user' is not defined`, и если я угадал, то этого самого `user` вам следует создать самостоятельно по советам из документации Flask-Login